# Why does “too many” sound wrong here?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage, grammaticality, differences

> I can’t believe I make too many mistakes in Turkish.

I’m a native English speaker trying help a friend understand why it sounds off to use “too many” here but I can’t seem to figure out why.

To me, “so many” sounds much better. Does anyone have a grammatical explanation for why it doesn’t really work with “too many”?

Comment: Depends on context and inflection.

Comment: If I told you that you make too many mistakes in Turkish and you can’t believe that then that’s a perfectly reasonable thing to say.  But it doesn’t mean the same as “so many”.

Comment: @Jim yeah, he had wanted to say it without a comment like that, just after he made a mistake that he was embarrassed about

Comment: To me "*I can’t believe I make too many mistakes in Turkish.*" gives the impression that there is a number of mistakes that is acceptable, and that you have exceeded that number. "Many" must have a referent: e.g. "You have taken too many [apples]" = You have taken more [apples] than the number allowed.

Comment: @Jim In such a case I would prefer the phrasing "I can't believe I tend to make too many mistakes in Turkish." or "I can't believe I've been making too many mistakes in Turkish." I think the former should even fit the accepted answer's explanation, because "tend to" has got to be a weakening intensifier.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

*Too* equates to *more than necessary*, which isn't what you are wanting to say, apparently. *So* equates to *very*.

Notice that "I *don't* believe I make too many mistakes in Turkish" is perfectly normal; and "I *don't* believe I make so many mistakes in Turkish" sounds a bit odd.

*So* is a strengthening intensifier, and wants consistency from *can't*, which is also a strenghtened version of *don't*. Awkwardly, words that weaken the situation are also called intensifiers. Your sentence is trying to strengthen quantification of the mistakes, so *can't* and *so* work here. My sentence with *don't* is trying to weaken the quantification of the mistakes, so *don't* and *too* work as a pair.

Looked for, but didn't find, collocation data and analysis for verbs *do*, *can* and intensifiers *too*, *so*.

Comment: There is a more colloquial sense of *too* as *very*, however. "Huh, look at that -- ya don't see too many phone booths around, anymore, do ya?"

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason it sounds off to you as a native is that it could be interpreted in a different way than intended.

I can't believe I make too many mistakes.  => I don't think I make a lot of mistakes. 
I can't believe I make so many mistakes. => I think I make a lot of mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

This is idiomatic English meaning  roughly ".. that I make many mistakes," The word "too" is just a concession admitting that some mistakes are made.  For example, some of [these "too often" phrases](https://context.reverso.net/translation/english-french/doesn%27t+come+too+often) or this ["We don't see that around here too often"](https://www.hobbytalk.com/threads/we-dont-see-these-around-here-too-often.166093/) likewise don't use   "too" in the sense of "excessive."

Answer (score 0):

I think 'I can't believe' here is a red herring because it's just implying a surprise on the part of the speaker. So the question is why

> I make too many mistakes in Turkish.

sounds off.

*Too* is defined in [Oxford](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/too) as:

> To a higher degree than is desirable, permissible, or possible; excessively.

That is, you'd normally need a certain degree that is desirable, permissible, or possible, in context, in order to use *too*, and in the context in which your friend is using that sentence, such a degree is not apparent (not at least to you). Hence your feeling that it's off.

But unbeknownst to you, your friend might have thought of such a degree, in which case I think he or she can use *too*.

Comment: "I make too many mistakes in Turkish" sounds good to me. "Too many" means more than expected or acceptable

Comment: This answer is way off. The whole point is that "can't believe" has to go with "so many", and "don't believe" has to go with "too many".

Comment: `I make too many mistakes in [Turkish].` does not sound off to me. *I make many mistakes*, and *I make too many mistakes* are both fine and idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

"Too many" implies a goal.  Using it in your example, without reference to the goal, sounds wrong.

Try

> "I can’t believe I make too many mistakes in Turkish to use the
>   language as an effective means of communication"

It sounds much better.